# Solr 4.9 - how to use defaults, appends and invariant in the requestHandler

Tags: solr, solr4, requesthandler

I have 8 fields in my schema. I have 2 types of documents in the index. The first type contains the details of a book and the second type of document contains where all a particular book is referenced.

The reason for such a schema is to reduce the index size. The documents in my Solr index look like this -

```
doc1 -
uniqueKey - <someid>
id - 1
name - Solr
author - something
isbn - something else
subject - null
referenced - null
dataType - detail

doc2 -
uniqueKey - <someid>
id - 1 
name - null
author - null
isbn - null
subject - physics
referenced - 2011
dataType - reference

doc3 -
uniqueKey - <someid>
id - 1 
name - null
author - null
isbn - null
subject - maths
referenced - 2013
dataType - reference
```

I want to let my users choose the subject and/or year but display the detail document in the result.

To achieve this I use the `join` query which looks like -

```
q=dataType:detail&fq={!join from=id to=id}<userySelectedSubjectAndOrYear>&dataType:reference
```

I have to generate this query in my backend everytime; instead I would like to use `default`, `appends` and/or `invariant` in my `requestHandler` because most part of the query remains the same.

I tried to do the following in my `requestHandler`

```
<requestHandler name="/usage" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="wt">json</str>
 </lst>
 <lst name="appends">
   <str name="q">dataType:detail</str>
   <str name="fq">{!join from=id to=id}dataType:reference</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and pass the user selected subject and/or year as `/usage?fq=subject:physics` I do not get any results. According to the [link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#df), it should append the values. What am I missing? Will I have to write my own custom `RequestHandler` to get this?

Comment: Do you get any results if you build the URL yourself? Have you looked at the response to see what the URL generated internally after parsing is? I think I'd also try to avoid relying on join, and instead index the genre and year for each reference to each book.

Comment: @MatsLindh - I do get the required output when I request using the URL. I had 2 options 1. to have the genre and year as multivalued but it creates a cross join. 2. The other fields name, author and ISBN have other tokenizers and filters so if I have the data in all records then the index size increases considerably.

Comment: But what is the difference of the parsed parameters in the resposne when using the URL directly and using the appended version? The response from Solr includes a list in the response. Regarding the data structure, there shouldn't be a need for a join if you use multivalued fields to keep the year/genre/year:genre, and no need to duplicate data for the other fields.